# Correct JSON ouput iPhone json_encode

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get a correct json output for iPhone i'm using the code:

```
<?php
$post = array('items' => 1, 'title' => message, 'description' => description);

echo json_encode($post);
?>
```

And the output is:

```
{"items":1,"title":"message","description":"description"}
```

But i want a output with `[`

```
{
    "items": [
            {
                "title": "message",
                "description": "description"
            }
        ]
}
```

Can someone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$post = array('items' => array( 0 => array('title' => message, 'description' => description)));
```

(warning: untested!)